# boost::call_traits - Why is gcc giving false for this?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++11

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/call_traits.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

boost::call_traits<int>::param_type f()
{
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
        std::cout << std::boolalpha;
        std::cout <<
        std::is_const<boost::call_traits<int>::param_type>::value
        << std::endl; // true
        std::cout << std::is_const<decltype(f())>::value << std::endl; // false

}
```

**Question:**

Unless, I am doing something wrong, I think I should be getting `true` for both, but gcc 4.7.0 outputs `false` for the latter. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A non-class type rvalue is never const-qualified.  Only class-type rvalues may be const-qualified.

So, even though the function `f` is declared as returning a `const int`, and even though the type of the function `f` is `const int()`, the call expression `f()` is an rvalue of type (non-const) `int`.

(In [the new C++11 expression category taxonomy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues), the call expression `f()` is a *prvalue* of type `int`.  The same rule applies:  C++11 §3.10/4 states that "non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types.")